# Unable to glue feature file to steps in behave appium python

Tags: python, appium

I am trying to glue the feature file with the steps. My project structure looks like the following:
[My project works fine without behave, now just trying to enhance from the framework](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJ8Kw.png)

test.feature looks like this:

```
Feature: test

  Scenario: test
    Given I open the app
    When I click on any language
    Then The language gets selected
```

test.py file:

```
from behave import given, when, then

@given('I open the app')
def step_impl(context):
    context.app.launch_page.get_hello_text()
```

environment.py (appium driver initialisation):

```
from appium import webdriver

from app.application import Application


def before_scenario(context, scenario):
    context.driver = webdriver.Remote("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub",
                                      desired_capabilities={'platformName': 'Android',
                                                            'platformVersion': '11',
                                                            'deviceName': 'Android auto',
                                                            'automationName': 'UiAutomator2',
                                                            'app': "/Users/snigdha/Downloads/test.apk",
                                                            'appPackage': 'com.example.app',
                                                            "appActivity": 'com.example.dot.Splashscreen'
                                                            })

    context.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
    context.app = Application(context.driver)


def after_scenario(context, scenario):
    context.driver.quit()
```

app.py or Application class which initialized all the page classes:

```
from pages.onboarding.app_language_screen import AppLanguage

class Application:
    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.launch_page = AppLanguage(driver)
```

After making all these changes, steps in feature file are undefined and no option to generate steps.
[Steps undefined even after I have added the steps manually](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpKLq.png)
Please let me know if I am missing out on something.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to restructure your folders a bit. Try this:

```
tests
├── features
│   └── test.feature
├── steps
│   └── test.py
└── environment.py
```